# What line(s) can I add to only pull unique values before counting all values and writing the CSV file?

Tags: r, excel, csv, tidyverse

I am trying to create a CSV file that is a list of all unique values in my dataset. My data is from a folder that contains 200+ CSV files all with 9 columns and a varying number of rows. Some files have no duplicates but many have duplicate values. I have found a code that lists how many rows in each file but I am wondering what I could add to it so it removes the duplicate values and only counts the unique values in the final output CSV. I would like the final CSV file to list the row count each of the 200+ files in one sheet.

The code I found is below

```
library(tidyverse)

csv.file <- list.files("TestA") # Directory with your .csv files
data.frame.output <- data.frame(number_of_cols = NA,
                                number_of_rows = NA,
                                name_of_csv = NA) #The df to be written

MyF <- function(x){
  
  csv.read.file <- data.table::fread(
    paste("TestA", x, sep = "/")
  )
  
  number.of.cols <- ncol(csv.read.file)
  
  number.of.rows <- nrow(csv.read.file)
  
  
  data.frame.output <<- add_row(data.frame.output,
                                number_of_cols = number.of.cols,
                                number_of_rows = number.of.rows,
                                name_of_csv = str_remove_all(x,".csv")) %>% 
    filter(!is.na(name_of_csv))
  
}

map(csv.file, MyF)
data.table::fwrite(data.frame.output, file = "Output1.csv")
```

I appreciate any guidance as I am a total R/coding beginner.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate values so that a row is eliminated if any of its values match a value in another row? Do the duplicates have to be in the same file or any file? Or duplicate rows so that all values in one row match all values in another row? Provide some reproducible data using `dput()` from a small sample of your data or some made-up data.

Comment: If I understand the question, your workflow is to read each file, remove duplicates and only then count how many rows are left. Add this count to a row of `data.frame.output`. Write the final `data.frame.output` to a CSV file. Is this it?

Answer (score 0):

The following function accepts a vector of file names, reads them one by one, removes duplicated rows and outputs a data.frame with numbers of columns and rows and CSV filename.

There is no need to previously create a results data.frame `data.frame.output`.

```
MyF <- function(x, path = "TestA"){
  f <- function(x, path) {
    # commented out to test the function
    # uncomment these 3 lines and comment out the next one
    #csv.read.file <- data.table::fread(
    #  file.path(path, x)
    #)
    csv.read.file <- data.table::fread(x)
    i_dups <- (duplicated(csv.read.file) | duplicated(csv.read.file, fromLast = TRUE))
    csv.read.file <- csv.read.file[!i_dups, ]
    #
    number.of.cols <- ncol(csv.read.file)
    number.of.rows <- nrow(csv.read.file)
    #
    name_of_csv <- if(is.na(x)) NA_character_ else basename(x)
    name_of_csv <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(name_of_csv)
    #
    data.frame(number_of_cols = number.of.cols,
               number_of_rows = number.of.rows,
               name_of_csv = name_of_csv) |>
      dplyr::filter(!is.na(name_of_csv))
  }
  #
  y <- purrr::map(x, f, path = path)
  data.table::rbindlist(y)
}

data.frame.output <- MyF(csv.file)

data.table::fwrite(data.frame.output, file = "Output1.csv")
```

---

I find this `for` loop version better. Though `for` loops are not considered very idiomatic in R, there is nothing wrong with them. Like the function above, it avoids assignment in the parent environment with the operator `<<-` and the code is simpler. The results data.frame `data.frame.output` is created beforehand with the number of rows equal to the length of the input filenames vector and assignment is done by replacing the `NA` values by each CSV files' values.

```
MyF <- function(x, path = "TestA"){
  data.frame.output <- data.frame(number_of_cols = rep(NA, length(x)),
                                  number_of_rows = rep(NA, length(x)),
                                  name_of_csv = rep(NA, length(x)))
  for(i in seq_along(x)) {
    # commented out to test the function
    # uncomment this line and comment out the next one
    #fl_name <- file.path(path, x[i])
    fl_name <- x[i]
    #
    csv.read.file <- data.table::fread(fl_name)
    i_dups <- (duplicated(csv.read.file) | duplicated(csv.read.file, fromLast = TRUE))
    csv.read.file <- csv.read.file[!i_dups, ]
    #
    data.frame.output$number_of_cols[i] <- ncol(csv.read.file)
    data.frame.output$number_of_rows[i] <- nrow(csv.read.file)
    #
    name_of_csv <- if(is.na(fl_name)) NA_character_ else basename(fl_name)
    name_of_csv <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(name_of_csv)
    data.frame.output$name_of_csv[i] <- name_of_csv
  }
  #
  data.frame.output |> dplyr::filter(!is.na(name_of_csv))
}
MyF(csv.file)
```

Comment: Hi Rui! Thank you for your help! You were right in your assumption, that is exactly the function I am looking for. I am trying your code however ran into one error. As I'm a beginner at this I'm not sure what I need to do to fix it. The error is: Error in purrr::map(x, f, path = path) : object 'csv.file' not found

Comment: @undreyuh This is your 2nd code line: `csv.file <- list.files("TestA") `. I assume you have the vector of CSV files created before calling the function. Also, read/follow the comments in the code about `file.path` right before `data.table::fread`.

Comment: Ah! Embarrassingly easy fix thank you! It does appear that some files have duplicate rows removed but I tested one file with Excel's duplicate value removal function and it appears the file I tested did not have all its duplicates removed through the code. Do you know what could possibly be the issue? I only tested because some files go over the 8808 value count indicating some remaining duplicates.

Comment: @undreyuh I have changed the `duplicated` code, see if it works as expected now.

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and now the counts are lower than before and still do not match the values from the Excel test.